# Matlab - creating an automatically animation transition for a line

Tags: matlab, animation

I have the following picture:
[image: lines]

and I want to create a continuous transition. The blue line (-20deg-start) goes until become like (22deg - original), and then goes until become like (60deg-stop).
the code to generate this lines is:

```
>> clear all
>> x=[0 11 20 34];
>> y=[2 8 17 32];
>> z=[9 20 29 43];
>> v=[16 23 32 43];
>> w=[15 26 35 49];
>> t=[30 40 47 55];
>> figure
>> hold on
>> plot(t,x, t,y, t,z, t,v, t,w)
```

Is it possible with the help of Matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your code for generating the lines?

Comment: the code is: >> clear all
>> x=[0 11 20 34];
>> y=[2 8 17 32];
>> z=[9 20 29 43];
>> v=[16 23 32 43];
>> w=[15 26 35 49];
>> t=[30 40 47 55];
>> figure
>> hold on
>> plot(t,x, t,y, t,z, t,v, t,w)

Comment: Press "edit" above and edit your code into your question, remembering to format it as code. It is difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most. I recommend LuisMendo's answer haha. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example shows how to do a **linear transition between two curves**, provided they are both defined on the **same set of *x* values**.

```
x = linspace(0,1,200); %// x values
y1 = log(1+x); %// y values of line 1
y2 = 1-x.^2; %// y values of line 2
c1 = [1 0 0]; %// red
c2 = [0 0 1]; %// blue
plot(x, y1, ':', 'color', c1); %// plot first line
hold on
plot(x, y2, ':', 'color', c2); %// plot second line

tt = linspace(0,1,100); %// define time axis, between 0 and 1. Adjust "100" for smoothness
h = plot(x, y1, '-', 'color', c2); %// moving line. Initially coincides with line 1
for t = tt
    y = y1*(1-t) + y2*t;
    c = c1*(1-t) + c2*t;
    set(h, 'YData', y, 'Color', c); %// update y values and color of moving line 
    pause(.02) %// adjust ".02" as needed
end
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  It isn't too hard to adjust for the case where the two curves have different x-values.  Just run an interpolation on one of the curves (maybe w/ a spline) to find the values at the other curve's x-values

Comment: BTW,  if anyone would like to *shade* a region, just replace the line `set(h, 'YData', y, 'Color', c)` with `plot(x,y,'color',c)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can (well from what I understand you wish to achieve). You can put all your data into 1 big array and loop through each row and display it, with a small pause between each set of data.

Example:

```
clear
clc
close all

 clear all 
 x=[0 11 20 34];
 y=[2 8 17 32]; 
 z=[9 20 29 43];
 v=[16 23 32 43];
 w=[15 26 35 49];
 t=[30 40 47 55];

 %// Put everything in single array
 AllArrays = [x;y;z;v;w]; 

 figure 
 hold all 

 %// Loop through each rows
 for k = 1:size(AllArrays,1)
 plot(t,AllArrays(k,:))
 %// Make a pause to see output
 pause(.5)
 end
```

Output:

[image]

Is this what you meant? Or maybe a smoother transition?

Comment: I would like a smoother transition and I would like to keep fixed all the lines, except the blue one which I would like to go until middle line, and then until (60deg - stop). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Oh I see. I'll modify my answer a bit later!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me  a lot

Comment: @Benoit_11 I've posted an answer for moving a line onto another. I couldn't resist to create the animated gif :-) I hope you don't mind!

Comment: haha @LuisMendo not at all! You have my upvote your answer is very nice; especially updating the `YData` and `color` properties of the line objects that was part of my update plan :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 You had my +1 as well! Nice answer too!

Comment: thanks! Its hard to resist adding an answer with an animated gif! :)